# How to set the background color of Firefox' URL bar with userChrome.css?

Tags: css, firefox, userchrome.css

I'm trying to change the background color of my Firefox URL bar using [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/). Following [these steps](https://www.userchrome.org/adding-style-recipes-userchrome-css.html), I added the code below to my `userChrome.css` (inside `<profile>/chrome`):

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul),
               url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml) {
    #urlbar {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

It didn't work at all. How could I get to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you need to set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference to `true` in `about:config`, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Tutorial/Modifying_the_Default_Skin).

Now, the right CSS identifier to be used is `#urlbar-background`:

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul),
               url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml) {
    #urlbar-background{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

(I learned that from [this file](https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/compact_urlbar_megabar.css); the whole repository is quite instructive.)